# "+" in Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

This is example code for a [Cancellation via explicit job](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#cancellation-via-explicit-job) for Kotlin Coroutines:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val job = Job() // create a job object to manage our lifecycle

    // now launch ten coroutines for a demo, each working for a different time
    val coroutines = List(10) { i ->
        // they are all children of our job object
        launch(coroutineContext + job) { // we use the context of main runBlocking thread, but with our own job object
            delay((i + 1) * 200L) // variable delay 200ms, 400ms, ... etc
            println("Coroutine $i is done")
        }
    }
    println("Launched ${coroutines.size} coroutines")
    delay(500L) // delay for half a second
    println("Cancelling the job!")
    job.cancelAndJoin() // cancel all our coroutines and wait for all of them to complete
}
```

I am confused about `+` in the expression `coroutineContext + job`?

What it is doing? Is it operator overwriting?

Comment: It's explained in the same doc: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#combining-contexts

Comment: It seems "+" operator symbolically adds one "nesting level" in the list of current coroutine contexts. It makes possible the later "join" to nested coroutines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s an example of [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html).
The following shows the documentation of method `CoroutineContext::plus`:

```
open operator fun plus(context: CoroutineContext): CoroutineContext
```

> Returns a context containing elements from this context and elements from other context. The elements from this context with the same key as in the other one are dropped.

It’s basically a merge of two contexts.

Comment: It is worth noting here, that you can always navigate to the corresponding method to see its documentation by Ctrl+Click (Cmd+Click on Mac) on `+` symbol in your code in IDEA.

Comment: `launch(coroutineContext + job) {}` is the same as `launch(coroutineContext.plus(job) {}`, which is the short form.